# Very fast files opening in Emacs similar to Sublime's Goto Anything

Tags: file, emacs, sublimetext2

Is it possible to open files in Emacs in way that Sublime Text 2 does (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)?
I miss this feature so much.

Comment: You're probably looking for [Superuser](http://www.superuser.com) or [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow is mainly for programming questions, whereas these other StackExchange sites are for these kinds of purposes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check out [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile). It was basically created to provide something similar to `C-p`, but has a lot of extra project level features as well. Projectile also has a Helm plugin to display project files and buffers with Helm.

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm)? It provides a unified history and buffer selector, which looks similar to what you want. You could bind the `helm-mini` command to a convenient key like F5.

[image: Helm-mini]

Comment: Helm is great, but by default doesn't include any *project* management plugins. I recommend taking a look at [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) and it's helm plugin if you're looking for project aware helm backend.

Comment: Just a note: `helm` is what happened to [anything](http://www.emacswiki.org/Anything#toc1).

Comment: What color scheme is that?

Comment: That's the normal colours in a solarized terminal. These days I use Emacs.app on OS X with bbatsov's version of solarized-theme.